# IzPack: is possible to create one app updater?

Tags: izpack

I created one installer with IzPack. Everything works fine. Now I'm wondering, is there a good way to create one installer that will take care of update the application if this already exists?

I tested running the installer again, but he not recognize that the application is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I have used IzPack for installing and updating.  IzPack does not natively tie in with any packaging system so there is no way for IzPack to conclusively know if something has been installed.  You might try to interact with registry or some specific flie you create at install time but that is still messy (to me anyway).

IzPack does however check if a file already exists before overwriting it so if you are running an update then an example is that you would want binaries to be updated but user configuration left alone so do something like this inside the packs element:

```
<packs>
    <pack name="CorePack" required="yes" preselected="yes">
        <description>The core of the app.</description>
        <file src="bin/binaryapp" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/bin"
            override="true">
            <os family="unix" />
        </file>
        <file src="etc/config.conf" targetdir="/etc/appdir">
             <os family="unix" />
        </file>
    </pack>
</packs>
```

You see that the binary has override="true" where the config does not (by default override=false).  Binary gets updated, config does not.

Jeff

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the user can change the installation path and in this case your software wont be updated and you will have duplicate installations.

Answer (score 0):

CheckedHelloPanel will do your job, at least for windows. It writes something to the registry and checks this if you try to reinstall.